# Send location details as JSON string to server in ionic3-angular4[Edited]

Tags: angular, object, location, tracking, ionic3

I am a newbie to **ionic** framework. Currently working in combination of **ionic3-angular4**. In my app, I need to **send the location details** of the user(once every 100 meters the user moves) **to the server** which request a **JSON string** with the location details in it. Using very few examples I found online, I coded the below given code by using **BackgroundGeolocation**. The problem is I get the location details as expected, but I am unable to hit the server. I have created a JSON string as expected by the server and send it, even though I am unable to hit the server. I could not find any tutorial online sending location details as a JSON string either. Could someone help me on this. Below is my location tracker code:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { BackgroundGeolocation, BackgroundGeolocationConfig } from'@ionic-native/background-geolocation';
import { Geolocation, Geoposition } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import { Toast } from '@ionic-native/toast';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';


@Injectable()
export class LocationTracker {

  public watch: any;
  public lat: number = 0;
  public lng: number = 0;
  public timing: any;
  public locationJson: string;


 constructor(public zone: NgZone, private backgroundGeolocation: BackgroundGeolocation, private geolocation: Geolocation, private toastCtrl: ToastController) {}


 startTracking() {    

  // Background Tracking

  let config = {

  desiredAccuracy: 0,      
  locationProvider: 1,

  //For testing purpose, I've given 1 metre although the target is 100 metres
  distanceFilter: 1,
  stationaryRadius: 1,
  debug: true,
  interval: 30000, //30 secs
  fastInterval: 15000, //15 secs
  activitiesInterval: (15000),
  url: 'http://192.168.100.14:8084/CAPWS' + '/ULD/' + this.locationJson,
  syncThreshold: 100,
  stopOnTerminate: false,
  startForeground: true,
  startOnBoot: true,
  stopOnStillActivity: false,
  pauseLocationUpdates: false
};

this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config).subscribe((location) => {

  console.log('BackgroundGeolocation:  ' + location.latitude + ',' + location.longitude);

  // Run update inside of Angular's zone
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.lat = location.latitude;
    this.lng = location.longitude;
    this.timing = location.timestamp;

    console.log('backgroundGeolocation--this.lat: ', this.lat);
    console.log('backgroundGeolocation--this.lng: ', this.lng);
    console.log('backgroundGeolocation--this.timing: ', this.timing);        


    this.locationJson = JSON.stringify({
      userId: 'f3fceda259df80200159fd48c0ea14ab',
      batchId: 'f3fceda25c211882015c67f59e410acc',
      timing: new Date(location.timestamp),
      latitude: location.latitude,
      longitude: location.longitude
    })
  });
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

// Turn ON the background-geolocation system.
this.backgroundGeolocation.start();


// Foreground Tracking
let options = {
  frequency: 3000,
  //interval: 20000,
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  url: 'http://192.168.100.14:8084/CAPWS' + '/ULD/' + this.locationJson,
  stopOnTerminate: false  // enable this to clear background location settings when the app terminates
};

this.watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition(options).filter((p: any) => p.code === undefined).subscribe((position: Geoposition) => {

  console.log(position);

  // Run update inside of Angular's zone
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
    this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
    this.timing = position.timestamp;

    console.log('watch--this.lat: ', this.lat);
    console.log('watch--this.lng: ', this.lng);
    console.log('watch--this.timing: ', this.timing);

    this.locationJson = JSON.stringify({
      userId: 'f3fceda259df80200159fd48c0ea14ab',
      batchId: 'f3fceda25c211882015c67f59e410acc',
      timing: new Date(position.timestamp),
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude
    })

    console.log('locationJson===:  ' + this.locationJson);
  });
 });
}


stopTracking() {

  console.log('stopTracking');   

  this.backgroundGeolocation.finish();
  this.watch.unsubscribe();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs on [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/) the request is going to be a POST.
It looks like to me that you are trying to format this as a GET since you are adding `this.locationJson` to your URL query string.

The code that you provided works just fine at sending a POST request. Depending on what kind of server you are sending it to you might also have to set the `httpHeaders` option.

You should then get a JsonArray posted to your server that looks similar to:

`[
  {
    "provider":"fused",
    "time":1504290833000,
    "latitude":0.0000000,
    "longitude":0.0000000,
    "accuracy":20,
    "speed":0,
    "altitude":0,
    "locationProvider":1
  }
]`

Comment: The server side is fine. It gets hit when checked using `postman`!